# How to update particular table column of particular row on checkBox click

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a dataTable in which i have five columns. First , fourth and fifth columns consists of checkboxes. I want that if user select or deselect checkbox of a particular row then the all checkboxes of that row also effected. I am using viewScope. Is this possible with view scope ?

Thanks

Comment: so if he ticks one, all in the row are ticked, and if he unticks one, all in that row are unticked?

Comment: I subscribe to jk2 question. If the answer is Yes, why would you want that?

Comment: @jk2 yes exactly i want this. Is this possible? how can i do it. I want to do this because i have a requirement. I have h:selectOneMenu in first column, fourth and fifth. I want that when first column checkbox click then the fourth and fifth column checkboxes of that row is also effected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify the relative IDs of those checkboxes in the `render`/`update`.

```
<p:column>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="column1" value="#{item.column1}">
        <f:ajax render="column4 column5" />
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</p:column>
...
<p:column>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="column4" value="#{item.column4}" />
</p:column>
<p:column>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="column5" value="#{item.column5}" />
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would invoke a bean method when the tick changes in the first column. There you can set the calues for the other selects. After setting, refresh.